# Questions about how malwares might operate under wine

Tags: wine, security, malware

a recent scan by clamav found that a few exe files in the WINE directory are infected with a trojan (called Ratnim?). A have a few specific questions on what a windows malware can do under linux.

1) Can a WINE malware  (not designed for linux; only designed to run in MS Windows environment) put itself in the system start-up so that it runs everytime i boot the computer?

2)if i were to scan for a WINE program in the process list will i find something to indicated ( like a distinctive icon or a name) to identify it as a WINE application?

3) Can an application running under WINE take screenshots?

4) can an applications running under WINE get hold of my webcam feed? Say when i am in a skype call? (i run linux version of skype if it helps)

i use certain windows applications under WINE on a regular basis. My real concerns are really with points #3 and #4.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also http://wiki.winehq.org/SecuringWine . In theory malware can run in wine, but I have not seen an example of anything that worked. Take a look at the links.

Comment: i have looked at the links as well as read a coupe of articles by you (i think) and while i did learn a great deal and i am wiling to believe that a malware running in wine cant do much, i was hoping to get answers to those specific points. I dont think this question is a duplicate since there is nothing about the points i have asked for in those links.

Comment: The problem is that your question is quite broad. There have always been concerns about such things with wine and in general you run wine as a user and applications run in wine have the same potential  permissions and priviliges as the user running wine. So if your use can access and use the web camera, applications running in wine can too. With that said, wine is not windows and as a compaitibility layer there can be any number of reasons an application might fail to run. You would need to try be a little more specific.